# Django Mongo user name not unique

Tags: django, mongodb

I am using Django with a Mongo database. I tried to inherit the User model from Django right into my company model as follows:

```
Class Company(User):
    ....
```

Obviously this doesn't work because Mongo doesn't support multi table inheritance. Then I used the following setup:

```
Class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.Foreignkey(User, unique=True)
    ....
```

For some reason with this setup I can create users with the same username over and over again. Does anyone knows how to make the username and email address unique for the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a solution. I use thew following code:

```
Class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    ....
```

This works for me.